# how to add text while displaying MBProgressHud in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to add text while displaying progress hud.
But i don't know how to use it.
Please help me out for this.

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;

[hud hideAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:markerView animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
hud.label.text = @"Loading";
hud.detailsLabel.text = @"Wait 3 seconds";

//hide MBProgressHUD when process finish
[hud hideAnimated:YES];
```

download from this link: https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Answer (score 1):

u can set labeltext

```
 hud.labelText = @"Loading";
```

for details

```
hud.detailsLabelText = @"Details";
```